# While calculating median I am getting run time error for all the test cases in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
from statistics import median
a=str(input())
l=a.split(' ')
for i,v in enumerate(l):
    l[i]=float(v)
print('%.9f'%median(l))
```

Comment: Can you share your error?

Answer (score 0):

Try with some data validation to check the error,

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
from statistics import median

a = str(input('Enter the series of values - '))

try:
    l = [float(value.strip()) for value in a.split(' ') if value.strip()]
except Exception as error:
    print('Error while float conversion - {}'.format(error))
    l = []

if l:
    print('%.9f' % median(l))
else:
    print('Enter valid inputs.')
```